# How to Stop Python on VS Code From Showing Working Directory on Run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyenv, wsl-2

[Screenshot of what I meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDFDx.png)
I'm on windows 10 using wsl2 with Debian distro. I added python using pyenv. Every time I run a python script, the terminal **prints the python interpreter path along with the working directory**, and this is annoying me ever since. Is there anyway to remove this? if not, does anyone know how to hide this?

Comment: have you done a search on SO, because it annoys me every time this is asked (every few days)

Comment: of course. unfortunately, their solutions aren't what I'm looking for.. any ways, thanks for the time